# Removing a keyword from a value inside an object - JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove the word ".com" from my object. Currently I can convert the object into a string however my filter is not working.

```
const items = [
{
company: 'datadog.com'
},
{
company: 'google.com'
},
{
company: 'amazon.com'
},
{
company: 'facebook.com'
}
];

var names = items.map(function(item) {
return item['company'];

});


names.toString();

 var filter = names.replace(".com", "");

 console.log(filter);
```

Comment: What is the expected result? An array of changed names? An array of objects with changed names?

Comment: I would like an array of objects with the company value filtered to display "google" instead of "google.com" for example. Thanks

Comment: Should they be new objects, or do you want to mutate the properties of the existing objects?

Comment: new objects would be ideal as I would store both the url + name of the company in my DB

Comment: So try to write a loop that creates these objects. Call `replace` on every url to create one name. You already seem to know what `map` does, use it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
let names = items.map(item => item.company.replace(/[.]com$/, ''));
```

For each company domain name this returns the domain name with any final `'.com'` sequence removed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the way you are doing it as a base, you can do something like this.

```
const items = [...youritems];

var names = items.map(function(item) {
return item['company'];

});


stringNames = JSON.stringify(names)

var filter = stringNames.replace(/.com/g, "");

filteredObject = JSON.parse(filter)

console.log(filteredObject)
```

But I don't think this is the safest way to go about it, or what you really want (it is not an array of objects). I would do something like this, using es6:

```
const items = [...youritems];

const newObject = items.map((item) => {
    const companyNoCom = item["company"].replace(/.com/g, "")
    newItem = {...item, company: companyNoCom}
    return newItem
})

console.log(newObject)
```

This is safer to me, it keeps it an array of objects, and it is cleaner. It uses an arrow function and does not modify the underlying objects.

Comment: Your second snippet is good, but I'd create an object with two separate properties

Comment: Thanks Coby that worked perfectly, if i wanted to to replace google.com/amazon using this method what would i call before the regex 'g'. when i try .replace(/google.com//),g"") it comments out the code. Is there a work around for this?